# Android: Standalone Menubar - onPrepareOptionsMenu?

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, menuitem, android-toolbar

I have an activity which contains an actionbar at the top and a stand alone toolbar at the bottom. I want to enable/disable an item in this toolbar depending on the value of some variable. Note, that this is inside an fragment.

If I have a normal action bar menu, I can do this in the `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` method. But this method is not called for the toolbar, nor could I distinguish which toolbar, if it would be called.
How can I prepare the toolbar and its menuitems?

This is my toolbar xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/item_medizinische_daten"
    android:title="@string/medizinische_daten"
    app:showAsAction="always"></item>
</menu>
```

This is my code:

```
    toolbarBottom = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar_bottom);
    toolbarBottom.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_toolbar_medizinische_daten);
    toolbarBottom.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.item_medizinische_daten:
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Medizinische Daten clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                default:
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: What's stopping you from calling toolbarBottom.getMenu() and then using the returned Menu to change its children?

Comment: @Luksprong Good question: Nothing. Post it as an answer, and I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Toolbar` widget has a `getMenu()` method which you could use to retrieve the `Menu` that you inflate on it. You could then use that `Menu` reference and through either `findItem()` or `getItem()` find its children and change them.